# In a triangle cos(A),cos(B),cos(C) are in arithmetic progression.Then in what type of progression are its ex radii in?

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle cos(A),cos(B),cos(C) are in arithmetic progression.Then in what type of progression are its ex radii in?

What would be the simplest approach?

Answer (score 2):

basically we have

$$r_1=4R\:\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$

$$r_2=4R\:\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$

$$r_3=4R\:\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$

Now since $\cos A$,$\cos B$,$\cos C$ are in A.P we have

$$\cos B-\cos A=\cos C-\cos B$$$\implies$

$$2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)$$ $\implies$

$$4R\:\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)=4R\:\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)$$ $\implies$

Now just expand $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$ and $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)$ and use above formulas for $r_1$,$r_2$ and $r_3$ we get

$$r_1-r_2=r_2-r_3$$ So Exradii are also in A.P

Comment: Very nice, +1  .